# Facebook session invalid after closing an app

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I'm currently working on an app that uses the SSO login from Facebook. I've followed the tutorial on their developer website for iOS and now I have a working login and logout system :)

However, every time when I startup the app, the session is not valid (anymore) and it's asking me to authorize the app. Is it possible that the session keeps valid, even after I closed the app, and how would I implement that? I've already tried the following code:

```
// Restore previously saved Facebook credentials (If any)
delegate.facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FBAccessToken"];
delegate.facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDate"];

// Trigger SSO Facebook authentication if required
if ([delegate.facebook isSessionValid] == NO) {
    [delegate.facebook authorize:nil];
} else {
    [self fbLoginWithUsername:username andPassword:password];
}
```

But still it's asking me to authorize. It's very annoying for users to see the authorization window every time they login. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the `NSUserDefaults` string you use for the `accessToken` is not `nil` and that you are saving it correctly.

Comment: My accessToken is not nil when I save it to NSUserDefaults. After I've saved then, I use [defaults synchronize]. How would that be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer to extend the Facebook class with a singleton style category and implement:

```
static Facebook *shared = nil;

    + (Facebook *)shared {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if(shared == nil)
                shared = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return shared;
    }

    - (id)init {
        if ((self = [self initWithAppId:kFacebookAppID andDelegate:self])) {
            [self addSessionData];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)addSessionData{
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:kFBAccessTokenKey] && [defaults objectForKey:kFBExpirationDateKey]) {
            self.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:kFBAccessTokenKey];
            self.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:kFBExpirationDateKey];
        }
    }

    - (void)authorize {

        if (![self isSessionValid]) {
            NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_about_me", nil];
            [self authorize:permissions];
        }
    }

    - (void)fbDidLogin {

        NSLog(@"User is logged in to Facebook");

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:[self accessToken] forKey:kFBAccessTokenKey];
        [defaults setObject:[self expirationDate] forKey:kFBExpirationDateKey];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBDidLogin" object:self];
    }

    - (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {

        if (cancelled) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBLoginCancelled" object:self];
        } else {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBLoginFailed" object:self];
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBDidNotLogin" object:self];
    }

    - (void)fbDidLogout {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:kFBAccessTokenKey];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:kFBExpirationDateKey];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBDidLogout" object:self];
        NSLog(@"Logged out of Facebook");
    }

    - (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt{
        NSLog(@"Facebook access token extended");
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:kFBAccessTokenKey];
        [defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:kFBExpirationDateKey];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }


    - (void)fbSessionInvalidated{

    }
```

I know that code works. Luckily we won't have to do this rubbish in iOS6!

Comment: Yeah, subclassing the Facebook class and use it as a singleton is indeed better than having a Facebook object in the app delegate. I will try to implement this when I've resolve my original issue!

Comment: Well... you will have to use the facebook-ios-sdk unless you only want to support iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

I've found my error!

When I login, I save the key as `FBAccessTokenKey` but I tried to read the `FBAccessToken`.

Kinda stupid, I know ;) now it's working as expected!

Comment: This should be a comment. So my answer is correct then... please mark it as checked to accept the answer.